# Best environment for production using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp, server

I have a PHP MySQL application which is deployed on XAMPP server installed on a Windows Server(2008 R2). My question is, is it a good setup or should I do something better? 
The technologies used in the application are old. The XAMPP server along with PHP and MySQL is almost five years old. I need some hints and suggestions what should I do? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web App?  Workstation App?  What is the problem? If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  PHP and mySQL are 5 years better. Upgrade to current versions.

Comment: Its a Web App. I am not facing any problems as of now, but I am worried that someday this setup will fail to support the application further.

Comment: You have complete control over the environment.  If it works you have no reason to upgrade mySQL or PHP.  You can install and test the current XAMPP version while keeping the current environment unchanged.  Then if your app still works with the new version then replace the old version with the current.  But if you have no reason to use new features added in the past 5 years then you do not need to do anything.  If it works, nothing to fix.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will test it in new environment.

Answer (score 1):

Xampp is really meant for a development/sandbox environment not a production server.

I'd recommend either looking into Amazon Web Services ( AWS ) for something extensive or just getting a semi-dedicated or dedicated server with redhat if the application is limited in usage.

Migrating out of a sandbox environment is strongly recommended as long as you take care of legacy dependencies and launch it in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will look into your suggestions. BTW: I have been looking into configuring PHP, MySQL, and Apache separately on my own instead of using some ready to use setup.

Comment: I think that's the best idea. Get a server. Install LAMP stack yourself and migrate your application over.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Linux will be best, but my question is I have Windows server and its university's property. Should I do LAMP or should I configure WAMP on my own.

Comment: Working in restricted environment I'd ask your colleagues about your flexibility. Ultimately it's down to what's easiest/simplest when having hardware/software limitations.